# Disabling a button in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

In my game players have a balance and when they click the button it goes down by 5000, they start off with 20,000 when they reach 0, I want an alert to come up (i have that working) and the button to be disabled - I can't get that to work, can anyone shed some light please? All the functions are working perfectly btw I'm just trying to add in the disable button to the "Subtract" Function - Thanks!

here's the code I'm working with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function subtract() {

var Balance = document.getElementById("Balance");
var Fee = parseInt(Balance.value) - 5000;
Balance.value = Fee;

if(Fee <= 0){
alert("To Continue Playing - Purchase More Coins at - LINK");
}
}
</script>


<button class="randombutton"  id="aaa" style="float:left;" onclick= "
 randomImg1(); 
 randomImg2(); 
 randomImg3(); 
 randomImg4(); 
 randomImg5(); 
 randomImg6(); 
 randomImg7(); 
 randomImg8();
 subtract();
 foo(this);"/>OPEN PACK</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable a form element with javascript you set the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled) property to `true`.

```
function subtract() {

    var Balance = document.getElementById("Balance");
    var Fee = parseInt(Balance.value) - 5000;
    Balance.value = Fee;

    if(Fee <= 0){
        // Get the element and then set the disabled property to true.
        document.getElementById('aaa').disabled = true;

        alert("To Continue Playing - Purchase More Coins at - LINK");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I would thumbs up your post if I could :)